# Prove by induction on $n\geq1$ that $f^{(n)}(x)=n!a_n(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}$ for all $x\in(-1,\infty)$

Tags: induction, power-series, taylor-expansion

Prove by induction on $n\geq1$ that $f^{(n)}(x)=n!a_n(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}$ for all $x\in(-1,\infty)$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{(1+x)}$

I'm not sure how to prove this usually when I am asked to prove something by induction there are statements on both sides of the inequality that I can input values into but in this case I don't see how to do the proof.

Base case when n=1

$f^{(1)}(x)=1!a_1(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1}$
$=(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Induction hypothesis assume the equality above holds for n=k.

$f^{(k)}(x)=k!a_k(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-k}$

Inductive step show the inequality holds for $n=k+1$

$f^{(k+1)}(x)=(k+1)!a_{(k+1)}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-(k+1)}$

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: What is $f$, please?

Comment: what is $a_i$? is that the whole question?

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt{(1+x)}$@saulspatz

Comment: Prove by induction on $n\geq1$ that $f^{(n)}(x)=n!a_n(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}$ for all $x\in(-1,\infty)$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{(1+x)}$, I'm not sure what you mean by what is $a_i$ (I guess my question may not be very clear)@SiongThyeGoh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must differentiate $$f^{(n)}(x)=n!a_n(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}$$ one more time with reapect to $x$!
$$(f^{(n)}(x))'=n!a_n\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n-1}=...$$
chanching the variables from $n$ to $k$ we have 
$$(f^{(k)}(x))'=k!a_k\left(\frac{1}{2}-k\right)(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-k-1}$$
now we consider
$$k!a_k\left( \frac{1}{2}-k\right)=k!\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-2\right)\cdot ...\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}-k+\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-k\right)}{k!}=(k+1)!\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-2\right)\cdot ...\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}-k+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-k\right)}{(k+1)!}$$ and this is $$(k+1)!a_{k+1}$$ so we have
$$f^{(k+1})(x)=(k+1)!a_{k+1}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-k-1}$$
and the proof ends here

Comment: Ok, but I'm not sure what to do from there how can I input values into $(f^{(n)}(x))'$, or do the inductive step?Thank you for answering @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: I was hoping that you could elaborate I'm not sure how to do the inductive step or prove this equality holds@Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: What denotes $$a_k$$?

Comment: $a_k=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-2\right)\cdots\left(\frac{1}{2}-k+1\right)}{k!},$@Dr. Sonnard Graubner

Comment: so what gives $$a_k\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}-k\right)$$?

Comment: Well I ca see that
$a_{k+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-2\right)\cdots\left(\frac{1}{2}-k+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-k\right)}{(k+1)!}=\frac{a_k\left(\frac12-k\right)}{k+1}$, but I'm not sure what your getting at. I really do appreciate the help I'm just not seeing what the steps are, all of the induction proofs I have done so far have been simple inequalities nothing like this.@Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: This should be $$a_{k+1}$$

Comment: Could you please write out one of the steps so that I may be able to continue the proof myself?@Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: I will think about this problem tomorrow and posting the full solution!